# How to check in JPA if joined column contains data with condition

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jpa

I have two tables.

Person and his vacation plannings. For this question everything we need to know is that Person contains Id and vp contains this id as a foreign key, and year and start date end date. Person can contains more vp.
thus

```
    Person          VacPlan
    _______        ____________
   |id     |----->|pers_id     |
                  |year        |
                  |start date  |
                  |end date    |
```

I need to select every person who don't have a single record in vp for specified year.

Something like: `select from person where (joined vp where vp.year = :year) is not empty`

Do you have any ideas how to make this in JPA(eclipse link)

**EDIT:**
this is how criteria looks like

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
List<Predicate> subPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PersonVP> q = cb.createQuery(PersonVP.class);
Root<PersonVP> person = q.from(PersonVP.class);

Subquery<VacationPlanning> subquery = q.subquery(VacationPlanning.class);
Root<VacationPlanning> subRoot = subquery.from(VacationPlanning.class);

Expression<String> exp = person.get("personnelNumber");
subPredicates.add(cb.equal(subRoot.get("year"), year));
subPredicates.add(cb.equal(exp, subRoot.get("perNr")));
subquery.where(cb.and(subPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[subPredicates.size()])));

if (STATUS.FILLED.equals(searchFillStatus)) {
    predicates.add(cb.and(cb.exists(subquery)));
} else if (STATUS.NOT_FILLED.equals(searchFillStatus)) {
    predicates.add(cb.and(cb.not(cb.exists(subquery))));
}

q.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

q.select(person);
TypedQuery<PersonVP> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(q);

return query.setFirstResult(from)
        .setMaxResults(to)
        .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select p from Person p where not exists(
    select vp.id from Person p2 
    join p2.vacPlans vp
    where p2.id = p.id
    and vp.year = :year)
```

Comment: At the end I did not need join. `select p from Person p where not exists (select 1 from VacPla vp where vp.year = 2016 and vp.persId=p.id);` Criteria version in question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM person p 
WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(vp.pers_id)
              FROM VacPlan vp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *NamedQuery* for this job.
You declare a *NamedQuery* using @JB Nizet query inside your Person Entity file like that :

```
@NamedQuery(name="VpForYear", query="select p from Person p where not exists(
    select vp.id from Person p2 
    join p2.vacPlans vp
    where p2.id = p.id
    and vp.year = :year)")
```

And you can use this `NamedQuery` like that :

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("VpForYear");
query.setParameter("year", 2016);
```